# Mysqli function calls on separate page

Tags: function, mysqli

I am trying to make a function page that will open and close the db using mysqli, but it's not working.  Is this possible or do I have to literally open and close it everytime? Here is the code from the functions.php page:

```
    function opendb(){
    $mysqli = new mysqli();
    $mysqli->connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);
}

function closedb(){
    $mysqli->close();
}

function rundb($query){
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

Now, the opendb() function works when called, but the closedb() function returns the following error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to include the opendb and closedb operations into the rundb function.  Once I did that, it worked perfectly.